# How to track state change of checkbox in Flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I have a basic Flask app which changes state on checkbox toggle. It looks something like:

```
  <a href="/toggle/{{ id }}">
    <input type="checkbox" value="{{data.done}}" {% if data.done %} 
    checked {% endif %}>
  </a>
```

---

```
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    data = Data.query.all()
    return render_template('index.html', data=data)

@app.route('/toggle/<int:id>')
def toggle_status(id):
    data = Data.query.get(id)
    data.done = not data.done
    db.session.commit()
    return redirect('/')
```

---

An (updated) aggregate of the sum of ticked checkboxes (in a table column) is then printed on the screen. However this only works on Firefox, and on Chrome the change is not visible.

Any ideas on the issue, or a more robust solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's 2 things that are not great about this approach to the problem. 
1) You're using an anchor tag for a checkbox click
2) You're using a GET call for the toggle in your routes where it should be a PUT or POST.

If you don't want to use Javascript and you only want to use python and HTML, I would recommend making your HTML use a form. WTForms is a good forms tool for flask that should help you with that. When you submit the form, your backend (python) should accept a POST call that updates the id in the database and can redirect back to the page.

If you don't want a submit button and you don't mind using javascript. I'd recommend creating a onClick listener using a library like jQuery or react and sending a PUT request to your backend which hits your toggle_status route. This way, you don't even need to do a redirect, your frontend can stay in sync with the backend as you're making asynchronous calls. Here is a guide on how to do AJAX calls https://www.airpair.com/js/jquery-ajax-post-tutorial

Why should you use POST, PUT or GET? here is a good blog answering this question: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/the-definitive-guide-to-get-vs-post

Comment: Thanks, I tried this using JQuery/POST, toggle_status is hit and the DB is modified but the page is not re-rendering, unless I refresh the browser. Any idea why?
EDIT: Seems a bit of a hack but location.reload(); at the end js of the function works.

Comment: Flask is only concerned with actions that hit its routes. It only does what you tell it to do. So, if you hit a POST route, it will update in the db and return you information in the response. The only way flask will render the page for you is if you reload or redirect. The way to update the page is to use the information returned from the POST response and use JavaScript to update the page yourself.